# prefixed - what does this means

Tags: html, indexeddb, pouchdb

When i run HTML5 compatibility test in Android native browser then it see the IndexedDB support marked as "Prefixed", while in Chrome and other it is marked as "Yes".
I understand Chrome latest version has full support for IndexedDB but what does IndexedDB support as "Prefixed" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mozilla page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

"Because the specification is still evolving, current implementations of IndexedDB hide under browser prefixes. Browser vendors may have different implementations of the standard IndexedDB API until the specification has solidified. But once consensus is reached on the standard, the vendors implement it without the prefix tags. Actually some implementations have removed the prefix: Internet Explorer 10, Firefox 16, Chrome 24. When they use a prefix, Gecko-based browsers use the moz prefix, while WebKit-based browsers use the webkit prefix."

As per Josh's comment:
Use something like the following statement to ensure compatibility:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB;
```

The characters 'webkit' are the prefix. You might need to use them in Android, but you no longer need to use them in Chrome (a few years ago you did)

Comment: Yes, essentially, you would want to use something like the following statement to ensure compatibility: `window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB;`. The characters 'webkit' are the prefix. You might need to use them in Android, but you no longer need to use them in Chrome (a few years ago you did).